# ¿Como enviar un pdf creado con fpdf por correo mediante PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer, fpdf, smtp

sucede que tengo un código que me genera pdfs perfectamente con la librería fpd. Pero al final de este, le agregué otra librería con su código correspondiente para que me envíe este pdf generado por correo con PHPMailer, y lo que sucede es que, me envía el correo y el pdf, pero vacío y al abrirlo me dice que el archivo está dañado y por ende no lo puedo abrir.
Este es mi código.

```
<?php 
     $outmail = $pdf->Output('','FichaCETis26.pdf');


   require("class.phpmailer.php");
   require("class.smtp.php");
   $correo=$_POST['CORREO'];
   $mail = new PHPMailer;

   //Config SMTP
   $mail->isSMTP();
   $mail->CharSet='utf-8';
   $mail->Host='mail.cetis26.edu.mx';
   $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
   $mail->Username='contacto@cetis26.edu.mx';
   $mail->Password='**********';
   $mail->SMTPSecure='TLS';
   $mail->Port=26;
   $mail->setLanguage('es');
   $mail->From = 'contacto@cetis26.edu.mx';
   $mail->FromName='Cetis26';
   $mail->Subject='Pase de ingreso al examen otra vez alv.';
   $mail->isHTML(true);
   $mail->Body="Hola, este es tu pase de ingreso al examen.";

   $mail->AddAddress($correo);
   $mail->AddStringAttachment($outmail,'FichaCETis26.pdf');
   $mail->Send();
?>
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es que, primero me genere el pdf y después lo envíe por correo, todo en un mismo archivo, solo me falta que el pdf llegue completo, cuando lo descargo y lo quiero abrir me dice que está dañado y no se puede abrir. Les agradecería mucho si pudieran ayudarme, muchas gracias y felices fiestas!

Answer (score 2):

Yo empezaría por comprobar que el pdf esté en su ubicación, y esté correctamente grabado (por ejemplo, que lo puedas abrir con un lector de pdf sin problemas). Se que parece una perogrullada, pero no sería la primera vez que un pdf no se me graba en el disco, por ejemplo, por un problema de permisos.

Una vez comprobado esto, usa, en vez de `AddStringAttachment()`, `AddAtachment()`. Es el que yo uso y siempre funciona bien.

Otra posibilidad es que si el correo de destino es de hotmail o yahoo, casi seguro que tendrás algún problema con los adjuntos. En mi trabajo, tuvimos que adoptar la medida de incluir en el texto del correo un enlace al PDF en el servidor, para que si el usuario no podía descargarlo como adjunto, lo hiciera mediante ese enlace. Estos proveedores de correos son un poco exagerados con la seguridad.

El código que yo uso. Los valores llegan en la firma de una función y se usan dentro.

```
$objetoDeCorreo->IsSMTP();
$objetoDeCorreo->SMTPAuth = true;
$objetoDeCorreo->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$objetoDeCorreo->Host = "127.0.0.1";
$objetoDeCorreo->From = $matrizDeOrigen["correo"];
$objetoDeCorreo->FromName = $matrizDeOrigen["nombre"];
$objetoDeCorreo->isHTML(true);
foreach ($matrizDeDestinatarios as $destino) {
    $objetoDeCorreo->AddAddress(key($destino));
}
$objetoDeCorreo->Subject = $asunto;
$mensaje = $encabezadoGeneral.$cadenaDeMensaje.$pieGeneral;

$objetoDeCorreo->Body = $mensaje;
$objetoDeCorreo->WordWrap = 50;

foreach ($matrizDeFicherosAdjuntos as $adjunto){
    $objetoDeCorreo->AddAttachment($adjunto["fichero"], $name=$adjunto["nombre"]);
}
$resultado = $objetoDeCorreo->Send();
```

Este me está funcionando sin problemas desde hace tiempo. Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Hola, use AddAttachment() pero no envía ningún archivo, solo envía el texto del Body, cuando genero mi pdf me lo abre correctamente y al descargarlo igual, pero al enviarlo con AddStringAttachment() y descargarlo desde el correo, al momento de abrirlo me dice que está dañado, que no es un tipo de archivo permitido o que al adjuntarlo como correo no se descodificó correctamente.

Comment: Lo que estoy viendo que me llama la atención es que estás usando un servidor de una universidad para el envío (por la extensión .edu). No se si el Sendmail que tenga esa red estará limitado. Yo que tú lo probaría desde tu propio ordenador, con la red de casa, y poniendo como servidor el localhost.

Te añado en la respuesta un código que uso en una aplicación en mi trabajo. Es antigua, pero está funcionando, tanto en desarrollo como en producción.

Comment: La respuesta es `$mail->AddAttachment("path_file","exit_name_file");` como bien dijo @Chefito y es lo que hay en la documentación oficial. Si eso no funciona el problema es otra cosa

Answer (score 0):

En este caso estas usando fpdf y generado el pdf con:

```
$outmail = $pdf->Output('','FichaCETis26.pdf');
```

cambiala por:

```
$outmail = $pdf->Output('S','FichaCETis26.pdf');
```

para poder generar un string y luego adjunta el pdf con:

```
AddStringAttachment($outmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira, mi problema es que en `$pdfListo` tenia el nombre del archivo, cambié a "S" y el archivo ya se envía y se puede visualizar en el destinatario.

A mí me funcionó este código:

```php
$pdf->Output('D','ReciboOrden.pdf');

$pdfListo=$pdf->Output('','S');

$mail->AddStringAttachment($pdfListo,'ReciboOrden.pdf','base64', 'application/pdf');
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe qué hace el código que estás mostrando en tu respuesta. Por cierto, lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.